# Set color in button Android

Tags: java, android, button

I have a color define in colors.xml

```
<color name="gray">#9e9e9e</color>
```

I want to set the background color in my MainActivity I stablish a conditional that set the background depens the version of Android that the device has.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            {
                cobro.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray, getApplicationContext().getTheme()));
                cobro.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.gray));
            }
            else
            {
                cobro.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
            }
```

Actually I am testing in Android Lollipop, so the color has to be setting with the if statement, but neither of two forms setting me the background color to my button work, any idea? could anybody tell me what is the correct form to set the background color?

Comment: What is cobro? Try change background color of the root layout component of your activity.

Comment: It's a button, I want to change color when the button has been pressed, actually it's green but when I press it I want  change color to gray.

Answer (score 1):

On your Button XML, add an attribute like this

```
android:background="@color/yourColor"
```

But before doing that, you need to add yourColor inside your colors.xml file. The default value of colors.xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

Then just add yourColor there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
        <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
        <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
        <color name="yourColor">#yourColorCode</color>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Actually I have the button colored by this, what I want to do is to change color when the user click it.

Comment: Maybe this will be a solution for you

Comment: https://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/change-color-of-button-on-click-android/

Answer (score 0):

Use **ContextCompat** rather than deprecated **getColor** Method

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.L){
cobro.setBackground(R.drawable.btn_selector);
}else{
cobro.setBackground(R.drawable.btn_selector);
}
```

**btn_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/login_selected" /><!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/login_mouse_over" /> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/login" /><!-- default -->
```

Comment: I have already done that and not work, when I clicked it I want to change background color but actually does not do that.

Comment: ok. Got it. It means you want change background color when Button Click. Right ?

Comment: Exactly, I want to change color when button has been clicked.

Comment: Use my Edited Answer for your issue